# Dynamically assigning a value to a column in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have the following scenario:

This is my model:

```
TableA{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Column1 {get; set;}
   public string Column2 {get; set;}
   public string Column3 {get; set;}
   ...
   public string ColumnN {get; set;}
}

TableB{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Column1 {get; set;}
   public string Column2 {get; set;}
   public string Column3 {get; set;}
   ...
   public string ColumnN {get; set;}
}
```

Now, let say I want to copy (transfer) some values from TableA to TableB. For this, I created a table in my Database where I have all the relations of what column from TableA is associated with TableB.

I use the following code to get the columns that needs to be copy:

```
var listColumnsToCopy = db.TableRelationsAB.Where(tf => tf.Copy == 1);
```

With that I have a list of all the columns to be copy.

At this point I was trying to use a foreach statement in C# to go through the columns in the list and be able to assign a value only for those columns

```
 Foreach(var col in listColumnsToCopy){
   TableA.col????? = "some value";   ---> HERE
 }
```

The above code is a replacement of doing it manually column by column:

```
TableA.Column1 = "some value"
TableA.Column2 = "some value"
...
TableA.ColumnN = "some value"
```

Is that possible? Will reflection work in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Brief answer: Yes

Detailed answer:
Yes, use can archive such behavior using reflection, just get PropertyInfo object of corresponding table type using its name as a matching criteria, and set desired value. But that will be slow. The fastest way to do that would be writing SQL store procedure, or at very least using dynamic compilation.

Answer (score 0):

yes, this can be done by something like this

```
var listColumnsToCopy = db.TableRelationsAB.Where(tf => tf.Copy == 1)
                        .Select(a=> new{ColumnA = a.Column1
                                      ,ColumnB=a.Column2??"some value"});
```

this will replace null values in Column2 by your value;

or if your Column2 has empty string instead of null you can use

```
 var listColumnsToCopy = db.TableRelationsAB.Where(tf => tf.Copy == 1)
                        .Select(a=> new{ColumnA = a.Column1
                                      ,ColumnB=a.Column2=""?"some value":a.Column2});
```